# Setting image data to a custom ISO character to be used in an HTML pseudo element

Tags: html, css, iso

I have seen a few websites that use the content attribute of a before/after pseudo element to set a picture as the content. The rule looks something like this:

```
:before {
    content: "\e91b";
}
```

But then it is rendered as an image. I believe it is this setting because I can replace that escaped character with `fooBar` for instance and the image changes to that. And replacing the content will change it back. Changing the colour attribute changes the colour of the image so I'm guessing it is defined with some SVG data somewhere. These are obviously custom set characters because it will be set to the company's logo or other random things.

I'm honestly stumped on how this can be done and Google searching revealed nothing, though I'm not entirely sure what to search for. Everything I found referred to standard ISO characters that can be used in the escaped manner for easier typing/dev work.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Probably it's a font, like fontawesome, check their site.

Comment: The thought occurred to me but on the site I am looking at I couldn't find where the font is being loaded. Just a few basic ones from Google Fonts.

Comment: Sure enough. This was it. Thanks a lot! Going to write a detailed answer of how to get the data here shortly.

Comment: Sure glad could help, if you could upvote my comment would be nice :)

Comment: Certainly! If you wanted to post that as an answer I would accept it and maybe just add my comments onto it about how to get the data. (technically the question was how is it done which is what you answered. In reality I was trying to extract the data from it as SVG which I was able to after your comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called CSS pseudo elements, take a look at: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/advanced/css-pseudo-elements.